# keras: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: keras

The same code as below runs well on **keras-0.3.3** but failed on **keras-1.0.2**.
What should I change if I want to run the code below on **keras-1.0.2**?

**Code**

```
en_de_model = Sequential()
en_de_model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                          output_dim=hidden_dim,
                          input_length=input_maxlen))
en_de_model.add(LSTM(hidden_dim))
```

**Error**

> File "/Users/kanoukoei/Desktop/encoder_decoder-master/encoder_decoder.py", line 167, in main
>       en_de_model.add(encoder_top_layer)
>     File "/Users/kanoukoei/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 142, in add
>       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>     File "/Users/kanoukoei/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 441, in **call**
>       self.assert_input_compatibility(x)
>     File "/Users/kanoukoei/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 382, in assert_input_compatibility
>       str(K.ndim(x)))
>   Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: Try changing dim_ordering from 'tf' to 'th' or vice-versa.

Comment: Can you show the values of `input_maxlen`, `hidden_dim` and `vocab_size`?

Comment: input_maxlen, hidden_dim and vocab_size is (5,20,51)